# Paint/ inside of stone wall

Tags: paint, brick, wallpaper

I recently moved into a ~150 year-old Victorian Terraced House in London. The people that lived in here before had glued some things to the interio wall that left some ugly areas upon removal.

I am now trying to figure out how to fix these areas. To me it looks like there is some layer between the now-exposed wall and the paint, but it does not look like usual wallpaper.

Could someone point me in the right way about how this can be fixed? Do I just use a thick paint (clay paint?) or do I need to do I need another layer first?

EDIT: upon further investigation, there does seem to be some sort of wallpaper (see last picture). Is there any way to fix the affected areas without changing all the wallpaper on the entire wall?

[image: Picture of Area 1]

[image: Picture of Area 2]

[image: last picture]

Comment: Step zero is the asbestos test, given unknown fuzzy layer in an old house.

Comment: I would guess this is paint over plaster, which was a common interior finish for stone and brick walls in the US ~125 years ago. (My 1880's house apparently had this, but lost most of it long before I moved in.)  At that age it might have been horsehair plaster.

Comment: Interested in hanging pictures there?

Comment: It's very low unfortunately. The glue was used to attach little barriers at the stairs for pets/ babies.